# Using Ansible hosts raises `--limit` does not match any hosts

Tags: vagrant, ansible, host

My `Vagrantfile` looks like:

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "vag-box"
  config.vm.box_url = "boxes/base.box"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.100.100"

  config.vm.provision :setup, type: :ansible_local do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
    ansible.provisioning_path = "/vagrant"
    ansible.inventory_path = "/vagrant/hosts"
  end
end
```

My playbook file looks like:

```yml
---
- name: Setup system
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  become_user: root
  roles:
    - { role: role1 }
    - { role: role2 }
```

My hosts file looks like:

```
[localhost]
localhost # 192.168.100.100
```

During ansible execution I get the following error:

`ERROR! Specified --limit does not match any hosts`

Comment: I can't get the same error as you, but basically you don't need the hosts file in the form you defined. You can run the playbook against `hosts: localhost` without defining the group `localhost`. Comment out the `ansible.inventory_path` and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: "localhost" is a name that is assigned to the 127.0.0.1 address by convention.  This refers to the loopback address of the local machine.  I don't think this is what you are trying to use it for, based on the comment in your hosts file.

Second: The Ansible provisioner in Vagrant usually creates a custom inventory file, with the required contents to provision the Vagrant box.  For example:

```
# Generated by Vagrant

myvagrantbox ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222 ansible_ssh_user='vagrant' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='/home/sage/ansible/vagrant/myvagrantbox/.vagrant/machines/myvagrantbox/virtualbox/private_key'
```

As you are overriding the inventory file, you will need to specify a similar line for the hostname of your vagrant box.

If you omit the `ansible.inventory_path = "/vagrant/hosts"` line from your config, it should JustWork(tm).  You might also wish to specify `config.vm.hostname = "myvagrantboxname"` in your configuration, so you know what hostname will be used.

See the [Using Vagrant and Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_vagrant.html) and the [Vagrant -- Ansible Provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: I think you should read the documentation first. The one that pertains to the question https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_local.html